# How to create a gzip file w/ FEXTRA & FCOMMENT fields

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a need to test if a program that I'm writing is parsing the gzip header correctly, and that includes reading the FEXTRA, FNAME, and FCOMMENT fields. Yet it seems that `gzip` doesn't support creating archives with the FEXTRA and FCOMMENT fields -- only FNAME. Are there any existing tools which can do all three of these?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The Crypto++ library honors all three fields in its [Gzip class](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gzip). Also see [Is Gzip supposed to honor original filename during decompress?](https://superuser.com/q/859785/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Many (most?) tools don't honor the filename by default because of troubles with character sets.

Comment: @jww Reread the description. Gzip only supports setting the FNAME field. The program I'm writing needs to parse the FEXTRA and FCOMMENT fields too, but I can't test these fields if I can't create a test file with gzip that has these fields. [See the RFC](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#specification)

Answer (score 6):

The Perl module [IO::Compress::Gzip](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/IO/Compress/Gzip.pm) optionally lets you set the three fields you are intrested in. (**Fair disclosure**: I am the author of the module)

Here is some sample code that sets **FNAME** to "filename", **FCOMMENT** to "This is a comment" and creates an **FEXTRA** field with a single subfield with ID "ab" and value "cde".

```
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError);

gzip \"payload" => "/tmp/test.gz", 
     Name       => "filename", 
     Comment    => "This is a comment", 
     ExtraField => [ "ab" => "cde"] 
  or die "Cannot create gzip file: $GzipError" ;
```

And here is a hexdump of the file it created.

```
00000000  1f 8b 08 1c cb 3b 3a 5a  00 03 07 00 61 62 03 00  |.....;:Z....ab..|
00000010  63 64 65 66 69 6c 65 6e  61 6d 65 00 54 68 69 73  |cdefilename.This|
00000020  20 69 73 20 61 20 63 6f  6d 6d 65 6e 74 00 2b 48  | is a comment.+H|
00000030  ac cc c9 4f 4c 01 00 15  6a 2c 42 07 00 00 00     |...OL...j,B....|
0000003f
```

Comment: It'd be nice if there was an actual utility (ie: gzip) that supported this functionality. Sadly, I had to instead open a generated gzip file in ghex and modify the hex data directly in order to create integration tests. Nonetheless, my C/Rust program is now reading these headers correctly.